# Can't access attr while looping thru controls of particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC 5 website. I have a particular row that, which a button is clicked, the row, with all its controls is cloned. Here's the master row that is cloned...

```
                <div class="row filter_row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="checkbox i-checks">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">
                        </div>
                        <select data-placeholder="Choose..." class="xchosen-select">
                            <option value="">First Name</option>
                            <option value="">Last Name</option>
                            <option value="">Account</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                        <select style="width: 50px; height: 35px;">
                            <option value="">And</option>
                            <option value="">Or</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="grouping" style="width: 40px; height: 35px;">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The adding/cloning of the row div works great. Now, what I want to do is this. When I select a NEW item in the dropdowns with class "grouping" then compare it to the PREVIOUS "grouping" dropdown. If they are equal then make the background-color of the div a different "alternating" color. (Basically the purpose of this is that this is an advanced data filtering modal and I want to color code the groups. So, if the first 2 dropdowns are group 1 the background is white, group 2 is an alternating color, group 3 is white, etc... Just to aesthetically help the user see his "groups" of rows. Hope this makes sense.)

The **PROBLEM** is that I can't seem to access the class or id attributes, etc... As test code I wrote this:

```
    $(".grouping").change(function() {
    // loop thru all selecting dropdowns
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id') + '>>>' + $(this).text());
        if ($(this).hasClass('grouping')) {
            // do the comparison, blah blah blah
            alert($(this).val());
        } else { 
            // for debug
            alert('class: ' + $(this).attr('class'));
        }
    });
 });
```

The issue is attr('id') and attr('class') show up ***undefined***. What could I be doing wrong? I believe I"m trying to access these properties correctly?

Secondly, for the main loop, of course, it's looping thru **all** dropdowns that are selected. I'd like it to only loop thru those with '**grouping**' class. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You are looping through the selected options. Is that you really want ?

Comment: "_I can't seem to access the class or id attributes_" You mean attributes for select or options tag?

Comment: Your `options` doesn't have `id` and `class` attributes

Comment: @Shyju Really I just want to assess the selected value(s) of each dropdown that has the 'grouping' class.

Comment: @palasH I was trying to see if the grouping class appeared in the dropdown or not basically.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2: updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over all selected `option` fields.

You need to loop over the `select` elements.

So, I think you just need to change this line:

```
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
```

To this:

```
$("select").each(function () {
```

Hope it can helps you.

Answer (score 1):

*I just want to assess the selected value(s) of each dropdown that has the 'grouping' class.*

You can target the elements using class selector and then get the selected value using `.val()`

```
$(".grouping").each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```